# Laravel error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219

Tags: php, laravel

When i want to insert data in the database i get this error

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219

I'm use resource controller

this is my form

```
<form action="library" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
        Enter the name of section: <input type="text" name="section_name"> <br>
        Upload an image: <input type="file" name="image"> <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create Section</button>
    </form>
```

and this is my store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $section_name = $request->input('section_name');
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $destenationPath = 'iamges';
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move($destenationPath, $filename);
    DB::table('sections')->insert(['section_name' => $section_name, 'image_name' => $filename]);
    return redirect('admin');

}
```

and this my Route

```
Route::resource('library', 'Main');
```

Comment: Set it in your form like this: `action="{{action('Main@store')}}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `action="library"`, so the form is submitted to `library`. But, here is nothing to deal with `library`. You need to submit the form to `store()` method in `Mian` controller.

Change `action="library"` to `action="{{ action('Main@store') }}"` in form starting tag.

Comment: I'm new in laravel and i'm learning in YouTube i but as you say but still same error

Comment: I'm now store the data in database but not redirect to admin area got the same error instead

Answer (score 0):

add this  `route='library.store'` to your form:

```
<form  method="POST" route="library.store" enctype="multipart/form-data" files="true">
```

and your rout should be:

```
Route::resource('library', 'controller_class_name');
```

Comment: sorry, remove action attribute

Comment: i removed the action attribute but also still have the same error :)

Comment: what is your class controller name, Route::resource('library', 'Main');
?

Answer (score 0):

Change you route to:

```
Route::resource('library', 'MainController');
```

Also, check out your controller. It should be placed into `app\Http\Controllers` directory, named `MainController.php` and it should include this code:

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
    ....
    public function store(Request $request)
    ....
}
```